# Is there something wrong with my code for my accordion menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I'm trying to make a sliding accordion menu, but when I click the buttons that are meant to trigger it, nothing happens at all.

Here's my code...

Also, if my code is just generally sloppy I apologize, I'm pretty new to this and am super open to suggestions for better practices!

Thanks in advance.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    //    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.nav {
  padding: 18px;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", "monospace";
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a {
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: #FFB52A;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

button {
  background: none!important;
  border: none;
  padding: 0!important;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion {
  font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", "monospace";
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  color: #FFB52A;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">

  <h1>header</h1>

  <button class="accordion">music</button><br>
  <div class="panel">
    <a href="artists.html">artists</a><br>
    <a href="draw-and-listen.html">draw and listen</a><br>
  </div>

  <hr><br>

  <button class="accordion">visual</button><br>
  <div class="panel">
    <a href="work.html">work</a><br>
  </div>

  <hr><br>

  <a href="store.html">store</a><br>
  <a href="about.html">about</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddler with your code?. First, add an onClick event to your buttons if you want them to make something. Those onClick should call functions where you do what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are looking for the element after the button to show/hide, but that's a `<br>` not the `<div>` with the content.
In the example below I simply removed the `<br>`

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    //    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.nav {
  padding: 18px;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", "monospace";
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a {
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: #FFB52A;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

button {
  background: none!important;
  border: none;
  padding: 0!important;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion {
  font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", "monospace";
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  color: #FFB52A;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">

  <h1>header</h1>

  <button class="accordion">music</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <a href="artists.html">artists</a><br>
    <a href="draw-and-listen.html">draw and listen</a><br>
  </div>

  <hr><br>

  <button class="accordion">visual</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <a href="work.html">work</a><br>
  </div>

  <hr><br>

  <a href="store.html">store</a><br>
  <a href="about.html">about</a>

</div>
```